# Parsing a dictionary into template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I have 2 models:

```
class Review(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="user_blog")
    tag = TaggableManager() 
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    review_text = models.TextField() 
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=True)
    hashtag = models.ForeignKey(Hashtag)


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    #inserir campo imagem
    #inserir slugify na url do produto
    url = models.SlugField(max_length=500)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='thumbs/')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=True)
```

I want to parse into a template all tags related to the product, product name and image.
The template is like this:

```
<li class="span3">
<div class="product-box">
    <img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}{{PRODUCT IMAGE}}" alt="" /></a></p>
<a href="product_detail.html" class="title">PRODUCT NAME</a><br/>
<a href="products.html" class="category">PRODUCT TAG</a>
<p class="price">$17.25</p>
</div>
```

In my view I'm doing like this:

```
def home(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        user = request.user
        prods = Product.objects.all()
        i = 0
        prodmatrix = {}
        for prod in prods:
            tags = Review.objects.filter(product=prod.id)
            for tag in tags:
                prodmatrix[str(i)] = [[prod.name], [prod.image], [tag]]
            i = i + 1

        return render(request, 'home.html',{'prodmatrix':prodmatrix})
```

My problem is that in the template, I'm just getting this:
[[U'KINECT XBOX 360'], [], []]
when I use a for loop like this:

```
{% for key, value in prodmatrix.items %}
```

The other problem is that, the product can have infinite tags, but I just want to parse 3 of them, so some produts will have 0,1,2 or 3 tags. How can i do this?

UPDATE:

This is how I'm doing:

for prod in prods:

```
    #                       0             1           2 
    prodmatrix[str(i)] = [[prod.name], [prod.image], []] 
    review = Review.objects.get(product=prod.id) #   ^ this is for tags 
    for tags in review.tag.all():     #                           
        prodmatrix[str(i)][2].append(tags.name) # append only tags 
        i = i + 1
```

And I'm getting:

```
KeyError at /
'1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct code, you are over-wiring same dict[key] position in loop as `prodmatrix[str(i)] = [[prod.name], [prod.image], [tag]]`,  you should append append:

**first way:**

```
for prod in prods:
    prodmatrix[str(i)] = [] 
    tags = Review.objects.filter(product=prod.id)
    for tag in tags:
        prodmatrix[str(i)].append([[prod.name], [prod.image], [tag]])
    i = i + 1
```

**second way**:
Or to just append new tags do as (I feel you need this one, same name and image for tags for one prod.id):

```
for prod in prods:
    #                       0             1           2 
    prodmatrix[str(i)] = [[prod.name], [prod.image], []] 
    tags = Review.objects.filter(product=prod.id) #   ^ this is for tags 
    for tag in tags:     #                           
        prodmatrix[str(i)][2].append(tag) # append only tags 
    i = i + 1
```

Suppose if you do as in second way then in template you need nested loop:

```
{% for key, values in prodmatrix.items %}
    {% for tag in values.2 %} # or if you wants just first three 
                          # values.2.0, values.2.1 values.2.2
```

Comment: @FilipeFerminiano show your template's code and complete error message